# How to decrement a values of variable in python?

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

Does anyone here who can help me what is the shortest way of decrementing a values of a variable?

Below is my desired output:

```
start = 5000
range = 5
qout = start/range

Distributed      Remaining
1000             4000  # start - 1000
1000             3000  # 4000 - 1000
1000             2000  # 3000 - 1000
1000             1000  # 2000 - 1000
1000             0     # 1000 - 1000
```

what i have done so far is this:

```
start = 5000
range = 5
qout = start/range
i = 0
while i < range:
    temp = {
            'distr' : qout,
            'remain' : start - remain, # This is what i can do only, unless it is being saved in the database so that i can move to next item.
            }
    i+=1
return temp
```

RE UPDATED:

I guess you are right, i don't know how should i ask. But let me show my original code.

```
temp = {}
i =  0
seq = 0
start = 11529.60 
range = 6
qout = start / range
remaining = start - qout
while i < range:
    while remaining >= 0:
        temp = {
                 'sequence' : i+1,
                 'distributed' : qout,
                 'remaining' : remaining,
               }
         remaining -= qout
    i += 1
 print(temp)
```

My expected output would like this **(and this is the output that i wanted/desired to show)**

```
Sequence     Distributed      Remaining
1            1921.60          9608.00
2            1921.60          7686.40
3            1921.60          5764.80
4            1921.60          3843.20
5            1921.60          1921.60
6            1921.60          0.00
```

How ever this is what i get:

```
Sequence     Distributed      Remaining
1            1921.60          9608.00
1            1921.60          7686.40
1            1921.60          5764.80
1            1921.60          3843.20
1            1921.60          1921.60
```

**Thanks for any help**

Comment: Why do you use a dictionary? It seems unnecessary.

Comment: So that it can have a **key/index** if that is the right term.

Answer (score 1):

This is my 3rd edit. I honestly believe that the largest problem here is that you can not define the question.

> How to decrement a values of variable in python?

The answer to this is `--i`, but that's not what you asking.
Than you have *desired input* with no explanation which is what.

That's how I guess you want it to work...

> `start` - an initial value;
>
> `range` - how many times `start` will be deducted from
>
> `quot` - amount of deduction, which is eq. to `start`/`range`.
>
> `remaining` - this is my variable, which reflect the result of deducting from `start`. From your comment below, **I assume** `remaining` can go negative.

Still no question here, but let's put it *together* ...

```
start = 11529.60
range = 6
quot = start/range
sequence = 0

remaining = start
while range > 0:
    range -= 1
    sequence += 1
    remaining -= quot
    print(sequence, quot, remaining)
```

Comment: The `range` and `start` actually is an input from the user. If he input 10 then the list will become 1 to 10. If he input 1240 as a start then the distributed is the quotient of the start and range. Regarding the remaining, what happen are these: **1st** ( start - distributed ), **2nd** ( result of the first - distributed), **3rd** ( result of the 2nd - distributed), **4th** ( result of the 3rd - distributed) and so on.

Comment: what is `factor` ? xD

Comment: Oh i am sorry, typo error. It's not `factor` its `range`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for help. I'll try it tomorrow, my project is in our computer lab.